# Is it possible to use grep lookaroud multiple times?

Tags: text-processing, grep

```
<table name="content_analyzer" another-key="id9">
  <type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer2" another-key="id12">
  <type="global" />
</table>    
<table name="content_analyzer" primary-key="id9">
  <type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer2" primary-key="id12">
  <type="global" />
</table>
<table name="content_analyzer_items" primary-key="id56">
  <type="global" />
</table>
```

if I want to extract the value of name then:

```
grep -Po 'name="\K.*?(?=")'
```

but how do I do it for the value of name and primary-key at the same time?
For example, the below line doesn't work.

```
grep -Po 'name="\K.*?(?=") primary-key="\K.*?(?=")'
```

so that it looks like

```
content_analyzer id9
content_analyzer2 id12
content_analyzer_items id56
```

Comment: It's Perl regular expression thing, not grep's. Also, parsing XML with regular expressions isn't the best idea.

Comment: If your xml was well-formed, you could do use an xml parsing tool, for example: `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//table[@primary-key]' -v '@name' -o " " -v '@primary-key' -n file.xml` -- that prints out the name and primary-key values for all table nodes having a primary-key attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/137158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -nr 's/^[^\s]+\sname="([^"]+)"\s.*primary-key="([^"]+)">$/\1 \2/p' file.txt
content_analyzer id9
content_analyzer2 id12
content_analyzer_items id56
```

Using `grep` with PCRE you can get:

```
$ grep -Po '(name|primary-key)="\K[^"]+' file.txt                         
content_analyzer
id9
content_analyzer2
id12
content_analyzer_items
id56
```

Comment: the grep -Po option works pretty close now i just have to bring id  and content_analyzer lier lines on the same line.I am not able to use the sed example because i my case its just a single big line and the `.*\sname` becomes greedy looking for the last name

Comment: @munish I have added the non-greedy `sed` way.. please check..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){if($i~/^name=/ || $i~/^primary-key=/){print $i}}}'
```

Result:

```
name="content_analyzer"
name="content_analyzer2"
name="content_analyzer"
primary-key="id9">
name="content_analyzer2"
primary-key="id12">
name="content_analyzer_items"
primary-key="id56">
```

`awk` will search for `name=` or `primary-key=` and print the value of that field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use *lookaround regexp* to select muliple parts of the line as intended.

However since you use perl syntax, perhaps `perl` itself is a better choice:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if s/.*name="(.*?)".*primary-key="(.*?)".*/\1 \2/' file
content_analyzer id9
content_analyzer2 id12
content_analyzer_items id56
```

This doesn't use any lookaround construct, and is self explanatory.

Comment: if he's using perl, he can use one of the XML-parser perl modules that are available (either pre-packaged for his distro or from CPAN).  regexps can't reliably be used to parse XML.